# File system access to Sharepoint document library - only approved items

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2007, document-library

How could I synchronize as SharePoint (2007) document library to a local folder... but only the 'approved' documents in a library that has content approval set on.

Navigating to it through Windows Explorer (i.e. the WebDAV link) exposes all files, but i can't find any indication in the file system which are approved.

Microsoft Office SharePoint Server 2007.  The client will either be Windows Server or a Windows client OS(7, XP)

Answer (score 0):

Windows Explorer view is always going to show you all the files so there isn't going to be a way to make it show a subset of the files.  With a tool written to use the SharePoint web services you could access a document library view that only had approved documents showing so you could only download documents that showed up in the view.  Alternatively you could query the document library for items that were approved and just grab those.